# 3D Lattice Boltzmann Method Python

Tags: python, simulation, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to understand how to implement a lattice Boltzmann simulation of a simple 3D object in python.

I would like to see the the object and flow in 3D but i can't find the right resources.

Can someone please point me into a direction on the best way to get the 3D simulation going?

Answer (score 0):

If you are tring to find the [Tutorial](https://feaforall.com/creating-cfd-solver-lattice-boltzmann-method/), I think it's the best tutorial even if you know nothing about fluid simulation